# Symfony Global function

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony1, symfony-1.4, dry

I want a function to be accessible from both action and model. What is the best practice for it keeping in mind `MVC` and `DRY`? The function is to be used by more than one models so it also does not make sense to make it a public function of a model.

Comment: Put it in a helper or utility class as a public method (static if possible) and call it there from all models that need to use it.

Comment: and put that where? It needs to be accessible to action as well.

Comment: helpers are accessible to actions as well :)

Comment: @prongs what is the nature of this function?

Comment: done. I followed the same approach as the one followed in `Jobeet` tutorial. There a class `Jobeet.class.php` is made in `/lib/'. That works

Comment: Strictly speaking, the model entities should only contain methods pertaining to the entities themselves. If there is common functionality then it should be abstracted from the entities as it's not entity functionality. If an action is looking to do the same thing then I begin to question what this task is, why wouldn't the action just call the method on the entity that it's manipulating ready for presentation to the view?

Comment: @Lazarus : Well, the actual situation is like this: 
I have a system to create images on the fly using some preset. I also want the user to be able to preview what he make. So I have a `preview` action. Now my global function does this: `$im=imagecreatefromjpeg();/*write some text on the image*/;return $im;` My preview action calls this and calls imagejpeg($im) to display the new image. On the other hand, in my model, I need to save the file to filesystem and filename to the db. there i call this global function and do `imagejpeg($im, $randomFname)` to save the image to filesystem.

Comment: Haven't you got an image class? This really sounds like functionality that belongs to an "image" object.

Comment: @Lazarus : Well, there is no image class. There are three classes(Model classes) which use image create functionality.

Comment: @prongs, if you don't have an image class then I'm suggesting you create one as it's the logical abstraction.

Comment: @Lazarus: or I could just say that this helper class is the image class since it has no other function defined in it. :-P

Comment: Each class should have a single responsibility so that argument doesn't exactly make sense but either way, getting this functionality out of your other classes so that it only occurs once in your source is the objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting it clean into an own object is better than a helper with mixed functionality as it makes (unit) testing easier and allows inheritance to fit each models invidual needs.